# jquery ui tabs - get loaded tab in load event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery ui tabs (from ui version 1.9.2), and the tabs are loading remotely via ajax.

In the API documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/tabs/#event-load), it seems to suggest that I can get the index of a loaded tab this way:

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    load: function(event,ui) { console.log(ui.tab.index());  }
});
```

However, this doesn't work.  I get an error because `ui.tab` is `undefined`

When I console.log `ui.tab` I get the full URL of the tab that was just loaded, leading me to believe that `ui.tab` is not the kind of object I'm expecting it to be.  I also tried using `ui.panel.index()` but I get the same `undefined` error.

I can get the index of an `activated` tab using the `activate` event and `ui.newTab.index()`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

Comment: `console.log(ui)` should tell you everything you need to know to be able to find the index, if it's possible at all to find it from `ui`.

Comment: How so?  When I `console.log(ui)` all I get is `[object Object]`.

Comment: Use a browser with a proper console, such as chrome or firefox+firebug

Comment: Could you jsfiddle your code? `ui.tab` should be a jQuery object in the `load` callback.

Comment: @KevinB  I am using a browser with a proper console--Chrome on Mac OS.  Is there some way I can get Chrome to depict the properties of this object?

Comment: You could try `console.dir(ui)`

Comment: @DavidBarker Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/octavient/h2e6f/

Comment: Thanks @KevinB  Using `console.dir(ui)` I'm able to enumerate the properties of the ui object.  However, `index` is not one of them.  Will this enumeration include both methods and properties, or just properties?  (I'm interpreting the inclusion of parentheses in the `index()` method to mean that it is, indeed, a method, and not a property)...

Comment: .index() would be a method of a jQuery object (which may look like an array in the console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that the jQuery UI docs haven't been updated or they are in error (and/or the intended implementation is not correct). `ui.tab` is returning the DOM node, not a jQuery object as the docs suggest.

This will get the index of the tab for you:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    load:function(event,ui) {
         var index = $(ui.tab).parent().index();

         console.log(index);
    }
});
```

If you plan on using the `ui.tab` node in that function for any other purpose it may be better to cache it first.

Comment: Thanks, David Barker.  This solved my problem, so I'll mark it as the answer.  Any idea where I can report this (the outdated documentation) to the jQuery team?

Comment: @octavient the docs are related 1.10.3, 1.9.2 did return a DOM node